# Referencing a class with the same name as an already existing type

Tags: java, class, types

I'm trying to reference a class by the name of "Entity", but when I use the following code
`Entity entityClass = new Entity();`
, an error occurs. The "entity" class itself creates a type of Entity, so I can't reference the class as it references the type within the Entity class.

Is there any reliable solution around this? I'm trying to edit a field within the class and I have no idea how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use its fully qualified name.  E.g.:  `net.bargle.Entity entity = new net.bargle.Entity();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in your "Entity" class you have the default constructor?

```
public Entity () { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1 - Check in your imports if you have import net.bargle.Entity or if you don't have to Entity class
     in differents packages.

2 - use the fully qualifed name as @marckspace said.